# what is the structure of my visual studio C# project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, tree

I am a beginner to .net and visual studio. The project I have been given contains multiple folders and each contains solution file and other folders, containing only .cs files and a visual c# project file. Is there something missing? do I need some main project file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Study about templates in .net. You are going to understand and clarify your questions about folders and solution and project file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will be solution since your question is rather wide.

To navigate across your project, you could use class diagram that is generated by VS.

[Visual studio class diagrams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2022)

and this link should give you better info about ASP.NET in general.

[ASP.NET overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/overview)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).